# "Bucket and chuck it" origin

Tags: etymology, phrases

Used in this sentence (by a friend):

> Well, if it doesn't work, just **bucket and chuck it**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The earliest Google Books match for "bucket and chuck it" appears to be this one from Michael Bouquet, [*Westcountry Sail: Merchant Shipping, 1840–1960*](https://books.google.com/books?id=m50FAAAAMAAJ&q=%22bucket+and+chuck+it%22&dq=%22bucket+and+chuck+it%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=3GxlVfvVBsTutQWthIGQBg&ved=0CEEQ6AEwBDgK) (1971) [snippet not visible in window]:

> The helmsman stands on a grating with his back against two teak rubbing boards on the wheel shelter. To port, the wheel shelter houses the lavatory (of the **bucket and chuck it** variety); to starboard, a lamp store and paint locker.

This is a boat-related example, but there is also this example from Suzanne Beedell, [*Water in the Garden*](https://books.google.com/books?id=WGRRAAAAMAAJ&q=%22have+a+clean+stream+running+through%22&dq=%22have+a+clean+stream+running+through%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=yHBlVbCwK4v6sAXuiYD4Ag&ved=0CDcQ6AEwAQ) (1973) [combined snippets]:

> ...just dip out the water with a **bucket and chuck it** around the garden, for even a small pool holds an awful lot of water (one of 6ft diameter and 15in deep holds 250–270 gallons).
>
> If you are lucky enough to have a clean stream running through your garden, then a small paddling pool with a continual flow of water is not too difficult to make. There is no problem about filling and emptying and keeping the water clean.

Another early match is from Paul McClory, [*How to Use Natural Energy*](https://books.google.com/books?id=JR0oAQAAMAAJ&q=%22bucket+and+chuck+it%22&dq=%22bucket+and+chuck+it%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=3GxlVfvVBsTutQWthIGQBg&ved=0CE0Q6AEwBzgK) (1978):

> When Paul and Mary Garton bought their Suffolk cottage the only sign of main services was a brass cold water tap. The wattle and daub structure, with Tudor brick floors, had been "modernised" around 1800. "The old folk here drank the water from the pond until a few years ago", said Mrs. Garton as the builders worked on the renovation, "and sanitation was of the **bucket-and-chuck-it**-variety".

Also, from Maurice Cloughly, [*A World to the West: A Voyage Around the World*](https://books.google.com/books?id=zqUGE1-LH4cC&q=%22bucket+and+chuck+it%22&dq=%22bucket+and+chuck+it%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=5WVlVbXrC4zBsAXlloHoAw&ved=0CC4Q6AEwATge) (1979) [combined snippets]:

> For several days we made poor progress in changeable weather while a variety of things on board went wrong. The toilet started playing up so we were forced for a time to resort to the time-honoured procedure of "**bucket-and-chuck-it**." Seams in the mizzen lost their stitching. Jib sheet blocks tore loose out of the track.

Another early match appears in Larry Brown, [*Sailing on a Micro-Budget*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Tvq_CPxkshMC&q=%22bucket+and+chuck+it%22&dq=%22bucket+and+chuck+it%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=zWVlVYHfO4uosAW1hYKYDg&ved=0CEMQ6AEwBDgU) (1985) [combined snippets]:

> Finally we come to everyone's favorite, the marine toilet. Coast Guard regulations forbid toilets that discharge wastes over the side. I find it strange that yachtsmen, who claim to love the sea, take such perverse pride in flouting the intent of this law. The law is worded in such a way that it is legal to go sailing with no toilet. Many sailors carry a sweet-smelling cedar bucket and operate on a "**bucket and chuck it**" philosophy...

And here is another from a non-nautical setting, in Association of Applied Biologists, [*Field Trials Methods and Data Handling: 16–18 December, 1985, Churchill College, Cambridge*](https://books.google.com/books?id=hg4bAQAAMAAJ&q=%22bucket+and+chuck+it%22&dq=%22bucket+and+chuck+it%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=zWVlVYHfO4uosAW1hYKYDg&ved=0CFEQ6AEwBzgU) (1985):

> The variability of the performance of pepperpot techniques for granules and hand application ('**bucket and chuck it**') for fertiliser, especially between seasoned hand and student has been noted and criticised by the farmers. No doubt a set amount of product has been dispensed over an area, but where, and how long has it taken? What is the coefficient variation with these techniques?

The "time-honoured procedure of 'bucket and chuck it'" may well have originated (as Josh61's answer suggests) in the context of boats with limited waste-disposal facilities on board—but it's not impossible that, in the days before indoor plumbing became commonplace on dry ground, "bucket and chuck it" might have been used to describe a waste disposal method used in lieu of plumbing or inconvenient outdoor privies.

It is also interesting that the same phrase is used for water distribution in a garden (1973) and for fertilizer distribution on crops (in 1985). Evidently, the human urge to gravitate toward rhymes involving *bucket* doesn't end with "There once was a girl from Nantucket..."

Comment: I think that the *chuck it* part of the saying may more reasonably  fit a *sea* context rather than an *inland* one.

Answer (score 2):

[Bucket and chuck it](https://books.google.it/books?id=3MwaPU4cI98C&pg=PA55&dq=%22bucket%20and%20chuck%20it%22&hl=it&sa=X&ei=WNhkVfqBEMi7swHl6IDYDQ&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22bucket%20and%20chuck%20it%22&f=false):

> - Supposedly from '*[beakhead](https://books.google.it/books?id=3MwaPU4cI98C&pg=PA55&dq=%22bucket%20and%20chuck%20it%22&hl=it&sa=X&ei=WNhkVfqBEMi7swHl6IDYDQ&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22FOA%22&f=false)*' part of  the *forecastle* used by sailors as a toilet.

(A B Sea: A Loose-footed Lexicon
 Di Jack Lagan)

> - ***The routine was to '[bucket and chuck it](https://books.google.it/books?id=0Bzh7uqd_T4C&pg=PA34&dq=%22bucket%20and%20chuck%20it%22&hl=it&sa=X&ei=y9xkVYzrHIOOsAGTkoDgBw&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22bucket%20and%20chuck%20it%22&f=false)'.*** You crawled to the bow end of the boat with baby wipes and the blue bucket. It was important not to confuse this with the yellow bucket – which was for washing up. Then you had to lower your shorts, ...(Wild Waters in the Roar
>     Di Mike Noel-Smith)
> - ***A The  [sanitary](https://books.google.it/books?id=EDCFnVV-WJgC&pg=PA86&dq=%22bucket%20and%20chuck%20it%22&hl=it&sa=X&ei=WNhkVfqBEMi7swHl6IDYDQ&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22bucket%20and%20chuck%20it%22&f=false) system had a simple name: "Bucket and Chuck It.***" The Jeanie Johnston's waste system is highly sophisticated, employing the latest technology presently used on ships and airplanes. 
>     (Jeanie Johnston: A Voyage Against All Odds)
> - ***Simple containers are modern variations of the traditional 'bucket-and-chuck it' [toilets](https://books.google.it/books?id=s73GAAAAIAAJ&q=%22bucket%20and%20chuck%20it%22&dq=%22bucket%20and%20chuck%20it%22&hl=it&sa=X&ei=WNhkVfqBEMi7swHl6IDYDQ&ved=0CFcQ6AEwBw),*** aiming to do little more than collect our deposits for composting. (Building Services Journal, Volume 20,Edizioni 7-12)